# C dup2 pipe delay with stdout, how to fix?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, delay, dup2

I can't figure out how to get rid of a delay, it seems like a buffering delay but I havent had any luck with setvbuf or fflush...

I have a c/c++ program that executes a python script which immediately starts printing to stdout (quite a bit), however there seems to be a huge delay when I try to read that input in my program.  I have tried to include a basic version of what I am doing below.  In the output I see TEST0 immediately and then after quite some time I get a huge dump of prints....  I tried setvbuff but that didnt seem to make a difference.  I think either I am doing something wrong or just not understanding what's happening.

Update: I am running in Linux.
Update2: fixed code typo with multiple forks
Update3: Adding stdout flushes in the python script fixed the problem, no more delays!  Thanks @DavidGrayson

```
int pipeFd[2];
pid_t pid;
char buff[PATH_MAX];
std::string path = "/user/bin/python3";
std::string script = "";//use path to python script here
std::string args = ""; //use args for python script here
  pid = fork();
  if( pid == -1)
  {
    printf( "[ERROR] cant fork\n" );
  }
  else if( pid == 0 )
  {
    close( pipeFd[0] );
    dup2( pipeFd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close( pipeFd[1] );
    execl(path.c_str(), "python3", script.c_str(), args.c_str(), (char*)NULL );
    printf( "[ERROR] script execl failed\n" );
    exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
    //setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    //setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf( "TEST0\n" );
    fflush(stdout);
    //it takes a really long time to see this next print
    read( pipeFd[0], buff, 1 );
    printf( "TEST1:%c\n", buff[0] );
    fflush(stdout);
    
  }
```

Comment: What operating system is this?  What are you doing in your *Python* code to to ensure that data printed to the standard output is flushed immediately?

Comment: @DavidGrayson I am running in Linux.  I am not doing anything in the python program to flush output but I will try that now.  When I run it from the terminal it immediately dumps output, but maybe in this case when running this way it will/could have a delay?

Comment: Why do you fork *three* times?

Comment: stdout is line-buffered by default _when it goes to a TTY_, but fully buffered when connected to a pipe or file. So yes, just because something is immediately flushed when you run it in your terminal doesn't mean it's immediately flushed in general.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I added flushes in the python program and that fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @HAL9000 sorry it was a typo should be fixed now, only 1 fork call

Comment: @DavidGrayson thanks for the comment, obvious solution and solved my problems as well